# Upgrading Angular.js from 1.1.3 to 1.1.4 breaks ng-submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm working on Angular app with a Rails API backend.  I have been having problems upgrading from Angular 1.1.3 to 1.1.4.  Before upgrading angular.js between versions a submit with ng-submit was working fine.  After the update it doesn't seem to be doing anything.  Nothing in the console and alert box within the controller is not being triggered.

Here is how the submit is defined:

```
<form ng-submit="create()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <legend>New report</legend>
  </div>
  <ng-include src="'/assets/ras_reports/_form.html.erb'" />
</form>
```

The controller (which is not triggered after upgrade):

```
app.controller "RasReportsController", ($scope, $http, $location, $state, $stateParams, RasReport) ->
  $scope.create = ->
    bootbox.alert "create"
```

Other functions within the controller work fine, i.e. populating the form, it only seems ng-submit has been broken.

p.s. I'm also using angular-ui-router.

Comment: living on edge has its drawbacks :)

Comment: Since 1.1.x is an unstable branch, it's possible something was broken in that build. Have you tried the more recent unstable builds? (The most recent at the moment is [1.2.0rc2](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/))

Comment: Yes, I tried 1.2.0-rc.2 which breaks it also.  It seems all versions after 1.1.3 are breaking it (I tried most of them :-) ).